# Validation Oscillating, tried different approach without good results

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a CNN with heavy hyperparameter tuning, and managed to get a 80% of accuracy on my discrete size dataset. However, I started overfitting and I completely failed to get better than this. This is my network:

```py
depth = 5
start_filters = 32
model = keras.models.Sequential()

for i in range(depth):
  if i == 0:
    input_shape = (img_h, img_w, 3)
  else:
    input_shape = (None, None)

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=start_f/2,
                                  kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                  strides=(1, 1),
                                  padding='same',
                                  input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=start_f/2,
                                  kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                  strides=(1, 1),
                                  padding='same',
                                  input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  start_f *= 2

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

[image]

I tried the following so far:

1. BatchNormalization, started facing oscillation
2. LR1 on dense layer
3. Increase Batch Size to 32
4. Augumentation - contained since it can possibly change the label;
5. Learning rate tuning

I've tuned depth and filters numbers to get to this result. Any suggestion?

PS: I got 80% on a previous fit on the same model, before applying the described actions - apart from augumentation

Answer (score 1):

You can try a few things

1. Check if you haven't applied preprocessing steps on validation data.
2. Your problem maybe more complex, so you need more layers/units.
3. Set smaller learning rate
4. Have you scaled/normalized your data in preprocessing step?
5. Use bigger data set
6. Try dropout (regularization )
7. Check out if you have unbalanced data set
8. The size of validation data may be small

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I have added the infos about depth and filters I forgot. I have done all suggested steps, apart from validation set resizing. Actually, my dataset consists of 5.7K Images, and 20% is used for validation. I cannot increase the dataset. I have not applied any preprocessing on validation, I've done it on training set. I will try set class_weight parameter on fit.

Comment: You should apply the same preprocessing in both train and val set.

Comment: isn't augumentation done only on training set? The preprocessing I've been using is just a rescaling ( rescale = 1./255 ) for training and validation, and I've added rotation, flip and zoom but with no success, only on training.

Comment: Yes , only on training. So you did apply the same preprocessing on val set (rescale). Because you said `I have not applied any preprocessing on validation`.

Comment: Well, I thought you were referring to non standard preprocessing via `preprocess_function` parameter in `ImageDataGenerator`. The only standard I've applied to both training and validation is `rescale=1./255`